# PHPStorm auto-complete not working with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using PHP Storm v8.0.3 with the latest version of Laravel.

I'm having trouble making the autocomplete work.

[image]

As you can see in the image above.

---

I have installed [barryvdh ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), following the readme he provides on git. I haven't received any errors during its installation.

[image]

I have included it in the `providers` array as either

`'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider'`

or

`Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider:class`

It didn't make any difference(as far as I can tell).

I have also installed the Laravel plugin.

Again, no difference, still no auto-complete.

[image]

I tried dumping the config file which resulted in:

```
array:27 [▼
 ...
  22 => "Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider"
  23 => "Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider"
  24 => "App\Providers\AppServiceProvider"
 ...
]
```

I'm really stuck on this one. I have no idea what could be wrong. Any nudging in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possible fixes for that:

1. Make your models extend the \Eloquent facade instead of
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.
2. If you prefer to keep using the
   "Model" facade, you can make your own alias in config/app.php,
   then change "eloquent" to "model" in the config/ide-helper.php under
   extra. This will let ide-helper include all the methods from
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder and
   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder which is where the missing methods
   actually live.

(Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpstorm-thinks-modelwhere-doesnt-exist-on-model-l5/replies/37661)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.
I don't know why I had all my Models extending "Model". (does the default laravel model have that?)
Anyway, \Eloquent does the trick and also saves an import of Model class.

Comment: If you want to keep the extends as `model` you can simply add `use Eloquent as Model;` at the top of the class.

Answer (score 5):

This article got me going with PHPStorm 2016.1.2, but it is one year older so I suppose it would work with older version.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/

The only details that are probably missing, I found them on the plugin GitHub link:

> After updating composer, add the service provider to the `providers` array in `config/app.php` 
>   `Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,`
>
> `php artisan ide-helper:generate`
>
> **Note:  bootstrap/compiled.php  has to be cleared first, so run  php artisan clear-compiled  before generating (and  php artisan optimize  after).**
>
> **Source:** https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: php artisan ide-helper:generate was the missing detail to get it work , thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the IDE Helper, you must enable the Laravel Plugin per-project in PHPStorm.

1. Open preferences.
2. Navigate to `Laravel Plugin`
3. Check `Enable plugin for this project`

Answer (score 2):

i tried all the Answers, but after i include `doctrine/dbal` for automatic phpDocs for models, the code autocomplete start to work because the automatic phpDocs for models added the `@mixin \Eloquent` and this do the trick and more ;)

steps:

```
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Require this package with composer using the following command:
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

After updating composer, add the service provider to the providers array in config/app.php
Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,

php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan optimize

You can configure your composer.json to do this after each commit:

"scripts":{
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},


composer require doctrine/dbal

php artisan ide-helper:models
```