# PhpStorm autocomplete Laravel 5 models

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm

I have installed Barryvdh class and the Laravel plugin for PhpStorm but I can't get the Models to autocomplete and PhpStorm throws warnings at me. I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744564/phpstorm-auto-complete-not-working-with-laravel-5) and many others to no avail. If I change my model from

```
class Promotion extends Model
```

to

```
class Promotion extends \Eloquent
```

Then it works. But I feel the fact having to change every single model is silly.Plus when making new models I will have to remember to change this.

Solution 2 looks like the better option. I have changed the `config/ide_helper.php` from

```
'Eloguent' => array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder', 'Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder'),
```

To

```
'Model' => array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder', 'Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder'),
```

I have then added this line to my aliases in `config/app.php` but I don't think this is right and don't know what is actually the right class to choose as this doesn't doesn't work, nor does the many other options I tried

```
'Model' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::class
```

I have cleared the cache and restarted PhpStorm many times now and have it running on 3 different computers with the exact same result. This seems so stupid and I feel so stupid, because it is probably so simple but can't see it.

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.1, Laravel 5.3